# Amazon EC2 Ubuntu with Apache "Forbidden" 403

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, http-status-code-403

I am setting up an AWS Ubuntu server.

I installed apache2, mysql, php and phpmyadmin.

I can access files under **/var/www**

but not under **/var/www/othersubfolder**...

It will say: Forbidden.

I updated apache2.conf with:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using apache 2.4+ you'll need to add this into your allow/deny rules:

```
Require all granted
```

So it would be

```
<Directory /home/user/path>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
```